# Usage of "felling night"

Tags: meaning

This is a quote from *The Name of the Wind* by Patrick Rothfuss:

> It was felling night, and the usual crowd had gathered at the Waystone Inn.

I have not seen the term *felling night* elsewhere before; was it made up by the author?

Comment: Probably explained here: http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/524241-how-long-is-a-span#comment_28503320 I'm not sure though. Or here, https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110820190957AAOaWGF

Comment: Apart from irrelevant collocations like *these twisting, tree-felling night winds*, and OCR errors *(felling = **falling**)*, all the instances in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22felling+night%22) I can read seem to be from *The Name of the Wind* (he uses it many times in the book). Note that a page or so after your cited line he writes *They'd been coming to the Waystone every Felling night for months*. And elsewhere there's *I can't tonight. Maybe on Felling. I'll be free on Felling*. Make of that what you will - I'd have thought it would be explained in the book.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is, there is a whole backstory, I can't incorporate it into my answer because it's a kind of a spoiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's made up by the author. It's the eighth day of his eleven day week that's calls a span. You'll encounter a lot more made up things. It's a fantasy book after all, one of the great ones.

There is a wiki for his books. It has a lot of spoilers, obviously. [Here.](http://kingkiller.wikia.com/wiki/Calendar_of_Temerant)

I won't cite why the day is called that way. Because, well, spoiler alert.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I assumed it somehow meant "falling", "nightfall". Silly me.